# How do I send an email with Laravel 4 without using a view?

Tags: php, email, laravel, swiftmailer

I'm developing a site using [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/docs/mail) and would like to send myself ad-hoc emails during testing, but it seems like the only way to send emails is to go through a view.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
Mail::queue('This is the body of my email', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('This is my subject');
});
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As mentioned in an answer on [Laravel mail: pass string instead of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139931/laravel-mail-pass-string-instead-of-view), you can do this (code copied verbatim from Jarek's answer):

```
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
  $message->to(..)
    ->subject(..)
    // here comes what you want
    ->setBody('Hi, welcome user!');
});
```

---

You can also use an empty view, by putting this into app/views/email/blank.blade.php

```
{{{ $msg }}}
```

And nothing else. Then you code

```
Mail::queue('email.blank', array('msg' => 'This is the body of my email'), function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('This is my subject');
});
```

And this allows you to send custom blank emails from different parts of your application without having to create different views for each one.

Comment: Great way to send plain text! Tanks

Comment: For the 1st solution, note that if you want to send HTML emails, you have to add another argument to the `setBody` function of "text/html" so that it becomes, for example, `$message->setBody('<p>Hi, welcome user!</p>', 'text/html');`

Answer (score 13):

If you want to send just text, you can use included method:

```
Mail::raw('Message text', function($message) {
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');
    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');
});
```

Comment: This method is only made in laravel 5 and the original post said larave 4 is used in the project.

Answer (score 0):

No, with out of the box Laravel Mail you will have to pass a view, even if it is empty. You would need to write your own mailer to enable that functionality.