# Laravel mail: pass string instead of view

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, swiftmailer

I want to send a confirmation e-mail using laravel.
The laravel Mail::send() function only seems to accept a path to a file on the system.
The problem is that my mailtemplates are stored in the database and not in a file on the system.

How can I pass plain content to the email?

Example:

```
$content = "Hi,welcome user!";

Mail::send($content,$data,function(){});
```

Answer (score 187, accepted):

**update on 7/20/2022*: For more current versions of Laravel, the `setBody()` method in the `Mail::send()` example below has been replaced with the `text()` or `html()` methods.*

*update*: In **Laravel 5** you can use `raw` instead:

```
Mail::raw('Hi, welcome user!', function ($message) {
  $message->to(..)
    ->subject(..);
});
```

---

This is how you do it:

```
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
  $message->to(..)
    ->subject(..)
    // here comes what you want
    ->setBody('Hi, welcome user!'); // assuming text/plain
    // or:
    ->setBody('<h1>Hi, welcome user!</h1>', 'text/html'); // for HTML rich messages
});
```

Comment: For **html** emails (needs extra argument) see @sajjad-ashraf 's answer. Might be good to merge?

Comment: true, added as in @Sajjad's answer

Comment: is it possible to use onConnection in that case?

Comment: and how to set text/html in laravel 5??

Comment: Unfortunately his won't work if you'd like to Mail::queue the message, throwing you the InvalidArgumentException exception 'Only mailables may be queued.'

Comment: It is good to mention that is preferable to use Mailable. But for those like me that was looking for a solution for the Mail::raw callback scope, you can use anonymous function as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4588842/5078248) shows.

Comment: @MarcosRocha +1 
feel free to suggest an edit to already accepted answer! it is how we improve and make (often pretty old) answers still relevant and better for newcomers

Answer (score 60):

For Html emails

```
Mail::send(array(), array(), function ($message) use ($html) {
  $message->to(..)
    ->subject(..)
    ->from(..)
    ->setBody($html, 'text/html');
});
```

Comment: Presumably you can set multiple bodies with different content types, and so have multipart emails with both `text/html` and `text/plain` parts to it?

Comment: @Jason The function (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L320) uses `addPart()` for the plain part instead of `setBody()` when a HTML part is set as well

Comment: Can you please help me with this i have body like this, $html = "Hello {{username}}", how can i pass username dynamically ?

Answer (score 18):

It is not directly related to the question, but for the ones that search for setting the plain text version of your email while keeping the custom HTML version, you can use this example :

```
Mail::raw([], function($message) {
    $message->from('contact@company.com', 'Company name');
    $message->to('johndoe@gmail.com');
    $message->subject('5% off all our website');
    $message->setBody( '<html><h1>5% off its awesome</h1><p>Go get it now !</p></html>', 'text/html' );
    $message->addPart("5% off its awesome\n\nGo get it now!", 'text/plain');
});
```

If you would ask "but why not set first argument as plain text ?", I made a test and it only takes the html part, ignoring the raw part.

If you need to use additional variable, the anonymous function will need you to use `use()` statement as following :

```
Mail::raw([], function($message) use($html, $plain, $to, $subject, $formEmail, $formName){
    $message->from($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $message->to($to);
    $message->subject($subject);
    $message->setBody($html, 'text/html' ); // dont miss the '<html></html>' or your spam score will increase !
    $message->addPart($plain, 'text/plain');
});
```

Hope it helps you folks.

Answer (score 13):

The Mailer class passes a string to `addContent` which via various other methods calls `views->make()`. As a result passing a string of content directly won't work as it'll try and load a view by that name.

What you'll need to do is create a view which simply echos `$content`

```
// mail-template.php
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

And then insert your string into that view at runtime.

```
$content = "Hi,welcome user!";

$data = [
    'content' => $content
];

Mail::send('mail-template', $data, function() { });
```

Comment: Not very elgant, i prefer Jarek Tkaczyk way :)

Comment: this answer is very misleading, don't know why op accepted this answer. Jarek Tkaczyk and Sajjad Ashraf have answered it properly

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue where the HTML and/or plain text of my email were not built by a view and I didn't want to create a dummy view for them (as proposed by @Matthew Odedoyin).

As others have commented, you can use `$this->html()` to set the HTML content of the message, but what if you want your email to have both HTML and plain text content?

Unfortunately `$this->text()` only takes a view, but I got around this by using:

```
$this->text(new HtmlString('Here is the plain text content'));
```

Which renders the content of the `HTMLString` instead of the view.

Comment: +1. This is the only answer that worked for me since I'm building the Mailable ahead of time, so I can't use the send() method. Disappointing that one would need this sort of workaround just to make a multipart email, when the HTML already has a way to be added as a string.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Mailtrap has a 'Text' tab which shows the plain text version of the email, for anyone using Mailtrap for testing.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
public function build()
{
    $message = 'Hi,welcome user!'
    return $this->html($message)->subject($message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

as you know

> Only mailables may be queued.

meaning, if you use `ShouldQueue` interface

1) first, you should always do

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

2) second, in your mailable you can use `html` method (tested in laravel 5.8)

```
public function build(): self
{
    return $this
            ->html('
                <html>
                    <body>
                        ForwardEmail
                    </body>
                </html>
            ')
            ->subject(config('app.name') . ' ' . 'email forwarded')
            ->attachData($this->content, 'email.eml', [
                'mime' => 'application/eml',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were using mailables. You can do something like this in the build method :

```
public function build()
{
 
    return $this->view('email')
        ->with(['html'=>'This is the message']);
}
```

And you just go ahead and create the blade view `email.blade.php` in your resource folder.

Then in the blade you can reference your string using laravel blade syntax

```html
 <html>
    <body>
      {{$html}}
    </body>
  </html>
```

or

```html
 <html>
    <body>
      {!!$html!!}
    </body>
 </html>
```

If your raw text contains HTML mark up
I hope this works for those who have templates stored in the database and wants to take advantage of the Mailables class in Laravel.

Comment: OP said they don't want to use a view.

Answer (score 1):

To send raw html, text etc using Laravel Mailables you can

override Mailable->send() in your Mailable and in there, use the method in previous responses:

```
send([], [], function($message){ $message->setBody() } )
```

No need to call $this->view() at your build function at all.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: Below answer is for those who are looking for a flexible approach. i,e (with or without laravel template)**

**With Template**

```
 $payload['message'] = View::make('emails.test-mail',$data)->render();
```

**Without Template**

```
$payload['message'] = "lorem ipsum";


Mail::raw([], function ($mail) use ($payload) {
    $mail->from($payload['from_email'])
        ->to($payload['to'])
        ->setBody($payload['message'], 'text/html')
        ->cc($payload['cc'])
        ->bcc($payload['bcc'])
        ->subject($payload['subject']);
    foreach ($payload['attachments'] as $file){
        $mail->attach($file);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 9 you should use `::html` method instead of `::raw`:

```
Mail::html('<h1>Hi, welcome user!</h1>', function ($message) {
  $message->to(..)
    ->subject(..);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished within a Mailable implementation, with plain text and html content parts:

```
  public function build() {

    // Text and html content sections we wish to use in place of view output
    $bodyHtml = ...
    $bodyText = ...

    // Internally, Mailer::renderView($view) interprets $view as the name of a blade template
    // unless, instead of string, it is set to an object implementing Htmlable,
    // in which case it returns the result $view->toHtml()
    $htmlViewAlternative = new class($bodyHtml) implements Htmlable {
      protected string $html;
      public function __construct($html) {
        $this->html = $html;
      }
      public function toHtml(): string {
        return $this->html;
      }
    };

    // We can now set both the html and text content sections without
    // involving blade templates. One minor hitch is the Mailable::view($view)
    // documents $view as being a string, which is incorrect if you follow
    // the convoluted downstream logic. 
    /** @noinspection PhpParamsInspection */
    return $this
      ->to(...)
      ->from(...)
      ->subject(...)
      ->view([
        'html' => $htmlViewAlternative,
        'raw' => $bodyText
      ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel mailable now has an `->html()` function to be used instead of `->view()` and works both with o without `->text()`

Answer (score 0):

laravel 9 has built in function to send HTML without view. Here is the example:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::html($content, function ($message) {
    $message->to("email@example.com")
        ->subject("Test dev 4")
        ->from("email@example.com");
});
```

and also if we use accepted answer will return:

> Symfony\Component\Mime\Message::setBody(): Argument #1 ($body) must be
> of type ?Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\AbstractPart, string given,
> called in
> /Users/yaskur/Sites/laravel/mail-builder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php
> on line 23

It's happened because laravel use new library to send email. Previously, use Swiftmailer and now use Symfony Mailer. To send HTML email without view you can also use below code:

```
Mail::raw("", function ($message) use ($content) {
    $body = new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\TextPart($content);
    $message->to("dyas@example.com")
        ->subject("Test dev")
        ->from("no-reply@example.com")
        ->setBody($body);
});
```