# Printing mail template from db table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to print the mail content from db table in laravel view blade.I have the table mail_template.
I want to fetch the field body from that table.

body field is a long text and value is in PHP content

```
body field value 
<?php

if(($logged==Auth::User()->user_name && $finance_review!='')|| $status=='Rejected'){
?>
<span>Hello {{$requestor_name}},</span>
<p>{{$approver_name}} has {{$status}} your Asset
request. Please login to <a href='asd.com'>http://systems.test.com</a>
&rarr; “Asset” and see your status</p>
<?php }
else{ ?>
<span>Hello {{$approver_name}},</span>
<p>{{$requestor_name}} has raised request. 
Please login to <a href=''>test</a>
&rarr; “Asset” and see your status</p>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to send the mail with filled content from fetched body field.
I have tried as

```
$mail_content=mail_template::where('config_name','=','approve')->first()->body;
echo $mail_content;
```

It just prints the content as text. I want to fill the value in variable

Comment: Maybe this thread could helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139931/laravel-mail-pass-string-instead-of-view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving the email templates as

```
<p>{{name_replace}}</p>
<p>{{email_replace}}</p>
```

After fetching the template from the database try using the php str_replace function on the template with values. For example

```
$template = str_replace("{{name_replace}}", "Zoe", $template);
```

I think this will solve your problem. Let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, this approach you have on loading the **email template**, so to say, from your database is awesome, the problem is that it is written in PHP.

Instead of storing the template in your database use views. Create, in your *\resources\views* a folder that will hold all your mail templates, in this case *folder*. And in your controller do this:

```
// Use Mail class, right on top:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

// Load the view to send
Mail::send('folder.view', $data, function ($mail) {
   $mail->from('from@email.com', 'Description');
   $mail->to(['to@email.com']);
   $mail->subject('SUBJECT');
});
```

Where:

- **folder.view** is ***view.blade.php*** view located in ***folder*** folder.
- **$data** is whatever you want to pass to the view.
- The rest depends on your preference, read docs: [laravel Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail)

Hope this info will be useful and keep coding.