# View [Mail] not found Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

## Am trying to send email with Laravel 5.4

But its showing

> View [Mail] not found.

## My Route code view below :

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});

Route::Get('/email','EmailController@index');
```

## My EmailController Code below  :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;
class EmailController extends Controller{
public function index()
  {
    Mail::send(['text'=>'Mail'],['name','Ripon Uddin Arman'],function($message){
        $message->to('rislam252@gmail.com')->subject("Email Testing with Laravel");
        $message->from('clhg52@gmail.com','Creative Losser Hopeless Genius');
    });
  }
 }
```

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 3):

In **Laravel 5** one can use `Mail::raw()`. One can also use the `Mail::send()` method with empty array as first argument, such as:

```
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
})
```

See: 
[Laravel mail: pass string instead of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139931/laravel-mail-pass-string-instead-of-view).

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.4 to 5.6 this send mail function is given as

```
public function send($view, array $data = [], $callback = null)
```

where first arg will be name of your view. So create a `mail.blade.php` in view folder write some text or html and save. Make change in your function as given below:

```
Mail::send('mail',['name','Ripon Uddin Arman'],function($message){
    $message->to('rislam252@gmail.com')->subject("Email Testing with Laravel");
    $message->from('clhg52@gmail.com','Creative Losser Hopeless Genius');
});
```

Pass the view name as first arg.

Hope this help :)