# Swiftmailer does not have a method body? How to use mail->body in laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
Mail::send('emails.contact-message', [
            'message' => $request->message
        ], function ($mail) use ($request) {
            $mail->from($request->email);
            $mail->Subject($request->name);
            $mail->Body($request->message);
            $mail->to('2725883@almatymadeniet.kz');
        });
```

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   class 'Swift_Message' does not have a method 'Body'

Only this Body doesnt work another subject from to work corectly

How to send message in body for gmail?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
Mail::send('emails.contact-message', [
            'message' => $request->message
        ], function ($mail) use ($request) {
            $mail->from($request->email);
            $mail->to('2725883@almatymadeniet.kz');
            $mail->Subject($request->name);

        });
```

**Updated Answer**

```
 $fromName = $request->email;



        $toName = 'Admin';

        $body = $request->message


        $subject = $request->name;


        $data = array('message' => $request->message);


        $fromEmail = $request->email;

        $toEmail = '2725883@almatymadeniet.kz';

        // Send mail for unsubscribe survey
        Mail::send('frontend.auth.emails.subscription_offer_user', $data, function($message) use ($toEmail, $toName, $fromEmail, $fromName, $subject, $body){ 

          $message->from($fromEmail, $fromName);
          $message->to($toEmail, $toName);
          $message->subject($subject);
          $message->setBody($body);
        });
```

Comment: Message doesnt sended( only subject and from

Comment: My questions have words like how to use mail->body

Comment: @Badzillazavr: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139931/laravel-mail-pass-string-instead-of-view)

Comment: Thank you very much but i anyway i have error like $request undefinded

Comment: @Badzillazavr: Thanks and glad to help :)